# wlan repeater ip-address difficulties

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm trying to setup my pi as wlan repeater for my existing wlan. I'm using two usb wlan dongles to succeed.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:1002 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v2 802.11n [Atheros AR9170]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0846:9001 NetGear, Inc. WN111(v2) RangeMax Next Wireless [Atheros AR9170+AR9101]

$ iw list
Wiphy phy1
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x184e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed, AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2,
           total <= 2, #channels <= 1
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * action
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * Unknown command (82)
         * Unknown command (81)
         * Unknown command (84)
         * Unknown command (87)
         * Unknown command (85)
         * Unknown command (89)
         * Unknown command (92)
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x184e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (30.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed, AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2,
           total <= 2, #channels <= 1
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * action
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * Unknown command (82)
         * Unknown command (81)
         * Unknown command (84)
         * Unknown command (87)
         * Unknown command (85)
         * Unknown command (89)
         * Unknown command (92)
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.

    $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wan
iface wan inet dhcp
wpa-driver wext
wpa-ssid "WLAN-SSID"
wpa-psk "PASSWORD"

iface lan inet static
address 192.168.234.1
netmask 255.255.255.0 

$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=lan
driver=nl80211
ssid=WLAN-REPEATER-AP
hw_mode=g
channel=11
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=REPEATER-PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
wpa_ptk_rekey=600 

$ cat /etc/dnsmaq.conf
interface=lan
#bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.234.100,192.168.234.150,12h
#dhcp-option=3,192.168.234.1
```

Here are some of the steps I performed, which are taken from this german tutorial http://blog.florianheinle.de/post/81479196987/wlan-repeater-mit-linux-selber-bauen

```
$ apt-get install ifrename wpasupplicant dnsmasq iptables hostapd
$ sudo nano /etc/iftab
wan mac 00:26:f2:95:5f:51
lan mac 94:0c:6d:e2:1c:d0
$ sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/dnsmasq 
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$IFACE" = "lan" ]; then
    /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
fi
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/network/if-up.d/dnsmasq
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/dnsmasq
$ sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/router.sh
#!/bin/bash
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wan -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface lan -j ACCEPT
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
$ sudo reboot
```

Stoping hostapd and testing it with the conf gives the following output

```
$ /etc/init.d/hostapd stop
[ ok ] Stopping advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd.
$ sudo hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: interface lan in phy phy0
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=208): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=2): 04 0a
nl80211: Failed to register Action frame processing - ignore for now
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 6 (MONITOR)
Failed to create interface mon.lan: -23 (Too many open files in system)
Try to remove and re-create mon.lan
nl80211: Remove interface ifindex=6
nl80211: Create interface iftype 6 (MONITOR)
nl80211: New interface mon.lan created: ifindex=7
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 7
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=30 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 11  Frequency: 2462 MHz
nl80211: Set freq 2462 (ht_enabled=0 sec_channel_offset=0)
Failed to update rate sets in kernel module
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Using interface lan with hwaddr 94:0c:6d:e2:1c:d0 and ssid 'Kitchen-WLAN'
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     4b 69 74 63 68 65 6e 2d 57 4c 41 4e               Kitchen-WLAN    
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=13): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Delay group state machine start until Beacon frames have been configured
VLAN: vlan_set_name_type(name_type=2)
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
WPA: Start group state machine to set initial keys
WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT (VLAN-ID 0)
Get randomness: len=16 entropy=0
GTK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE (VLAN-ID 0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=2 addr=0x88f0c key_idx=1 set_tx=1 seq_len=0 key_len=32
   broadcast key
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_operstate: operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=6
lan: Setup of interface done.
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x1002 ()
nl80211: Ignore interface down event since interface lan is up
nl80211: Ignore event for foreign ifindex 6
nl80211: Ignore dellink event for foreign ifindex 6
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x1002 ()
nl80211: Ignore interface down event since interface mon.lan is up
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'mon.lan' added
Unknown event 5
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'lan' added
nl80211: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'lan' added
nl80211: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Delete station 74:e2:f5:27:22:59
mgmt::deauth cb
VLAN: vlan_newlink(lan)
Add randomness: count=1 entropy=0
Add randomness: count=2 entropy=1
Add randomness: count=3 entropy=2
Add randomness: count=4 entropy=3
...
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Ignored event (cmd=64) for foreign interface (ifindex 4)
Add randomness: count=163 entropy=162
Add randomness: count=164 entropy=163
...
```

The WLAN is accessible but devices connecting to it are getting no ip-address. I assume there must be something wrong with my dnsmaq.conf.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone in the blog commentaries of the original tutorial pointed out that there was a missing 'S' in the file naming of "dnsmaq.conf".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this exact configuration, but in order for an associated station to get an IP address it's going to have to have visibility to a DHCP server.  Since you're doing wlan repeating, it would seem to me you're going to need to a bridge statement in your hostapd config file to bridge your AP mode wlan to your station mode wlan.  I don't have details on that, but unless you're bridged to a network with a DHCP server, you're not getting an address.

Comment: No answer at all. Just a generic and quite obvious: No dhcp. Missing multicast? Please check and confirm your facts before posting.